# Android disable Scrollview end animation

Tags: android, android-scrollview

There is animation when reaching the end of Scrollview with great velocity. The animation basically pulling the ScrollView up when scrolling down reaching the end, indicating that it's the end of that view. **How can i disable it?**

My situation is that the ScrollView sitting on top of another view that has dark background and it spoils it a bit with that animation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you mean over scroll effect which can be disabled in your xml

```
 android:overScrollMode="never"
```

or

```
 listView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
```